# Multi row to single row conversion in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot

I have below tables.

Table1

```
Col1,col2,col3,col4
1,2,3,''
3,4,5,''
```

Table2

```
col5,col6
4,5
1,1
```

Table3

```
col7
7
0
```

Want the output as below:
output table:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7
4,6,8,'',5,6,7
```

Could you please help with the above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate before joining:

```
select *
from (select sum(col1) as col1, sum(col2) as col2, sum(col3) as col3
      from t1
     ) t1 cross join
     (select sum(col5) as col5, sum(col6) as col6
      from t2
     ) t2 cross join
     (select sum(col7) as col7
      from t3
     ) t3;
```

Note:  Oracle treats `''` as `NULL`, so `SUM()` works fine on that column.